# What can interrupt execution of threads which are pinned to cores?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, performance, interrupt

I do low-latency application development and I use isocpu and set thread affinity to reduce (*eliminate*?) context switching during my critical threads. However, I am unsure what other types of interrupt my critical threads are still liable to?

Although I understand x86 CPU architecture well, I don't know a great deal about interrupts/context switches, the various types etc. When using `getrusage` it shows *voluntary* and *involuntary* context switches?

Kernel bypass is also used, so the network card writes data straight in to a user-level buffer- which may exclude some possible answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Check `/proc/interrupts` to see which hardware is handled by each CPU. Unless you configure all the processes and all the interrupts to use other CPU cores, the system tries to balance all tasks and interrupts to all CPUs. In addition, your motherboard firmware may implement some "hardware" with [SMI interrupts that may interrupt at least some CPU cores without OS control](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/trace/hwlat_detector.html).

Voluntary context switch happens when your programs asks something from the OS  (e.g. `open()`, `malloc()`/`brk()`, `sleep()`) and involuntary context switch happens when your program is continuously using CPU but CPU wants to interrupt the process to run some another process in between (either hardware interrupt handler or another user mode task).

List of stuff that can interrupt your process running with realtime priority:

- Other realtime tasks running on the same core with higher realtime priority.
- Interrupt handlers bind to the same CPU core.
- NMI
- SMI

And if your task is running as normal user mode process, any other process running on the same CPU (including lower priority processes) may interrupt your process.